# Scala generic that implements method toIterator

Tags: scala, generics, collections, iterator

I need a function that will take in an Array, a Map, a List [pretty much any container with a `toIterator` method], iterate over it, and print its elements.

I tried this:

```
def method[CollectionT <: TraversableLike[Any, Any]](collection: CollectionT, numElements: Int) {
  val iterator = collection.toIterator
  for(i <- 0 until numElements) {
    if(iterator.hasNext) {
      println(iterator.next()) 
    }
  }
}
```

^ But it does not work for Array[T]

How do I make a genetic function in Scala that will take in any instance of a class that has a "`toIterator: Iterator[A]`" method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A general type that you can use here is `GenTraversable`:

```
scala> def printAll(coll: collection.GenTraversable[_]) = coll.foreach(println)
defined function printAll
scala> printAll("aaa")
a
a
a

scala> printAll(Array(1,2,3))
1
2
3

scala> printAll(Seq(4,5,6))
4
5
6
```

You also don't need an iterator. You can more easily call `foreach` or use a `for` comprehension.

Comment: I would suggest using `GenTraversableOnce` (or `TraversableOnce` if you want to disallow parallel collections).

Comment: @PaulDraper - GenTraversableOnce is a superclass of GenTraversable. Did you mean "I would suggest using GenTraversableOnce if you want to allow parallel collections?"

Comment: @MichaelLafayette I think Paul meant “`GenTraversableOnce` instead of `GenTraversable`”.

Comment: @Jean-PhilippePellet Yes, but you would use `GenTraversableOnce` if you want to ALLOW for the use of parallel collections. Paul said "...using `GenTraversableOnce` if you want to DISALLOW parallel collections". But yes, in my print-locator library ( https://github.com/JohnReedLOL/scala-trace-debug ) I am using GenTraversableOnce. Thank you. p.s. Try my library if you are an IDE user.

Comment: @MichaelLafayette Paul wrote the reverse of what you wrote that he wrote.

Comment: Oh, I see. I missed the parenthesis. I read it as "I would suggest using GenTraversableOnce or TraversableOnce if you want to disallow parallel collections)."